# Is it possible to write configuration section handler by code?

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm programming new application with app.config file.

Here is my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="FTPServers">
    <section name="section1" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
      <section name="section2" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
</sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="Application">
      <section name="Section3" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
      <section name="Section4" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
      <section name="Section5" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
```

Is it possible by code to add a section in a section group as soon as necessary ?

I wan to create a form in my program to modify this configuration and It can be useful to create section group and after configuration section ...

Thanks

Comment: You can't modify application settings from code directly, only user settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify application settings from code directly, only user settings. That is, not with the usual API from which you can read the settings. Maybe you can use default text IO to edit the file, but it's not recommended.

This is because the app.config is used by all users who launch the program. One user changing the app.config while running the program can have surprising results for other users that are currently running the program.

You can use user.config to edit user settings or use a different config mechanism. The app.config is mainly for static configurations that only need to be changed by admins.

Comment: Ok thanks for support.
I'll continue to use this app.config but I'll coding only the method to change section settings...